# JavaScript interval function to count datetime

Tags: javascript, momentjs, setinterval

I have a function which Returns the time left betweens two datetimes, currently if I refresh I get the current time left to that specific date. Currently it only Returns the correct time left if I refresh, I tried to set create a setinterval function so that I get the time every few seconds but it does not run the function every second.

So far my Code:

```
import moment from 'moment';

const calc = {

    vars: {
        interval: null,
        releaseDate: null,
        currentDate: null
    },

    elements: {
        releaseAt: document.getElementById('release-at'), // 2018-08-31 14:24:00
        currentDate: document.getElementById('current-date') // 2018-08-18 17:32:59
    },

    render () {
        moment().format();
        this.nextTick();
        this.vars.interval = setInterval(this.nextTick(), 1000);
    },

    nextTick () {
        let releaseDate = moment(this.elements.releaseAt.value);
        let currentDate = moment(this.elements.currentDate.value);

        if (currentDate.isBefore(releaseDate)) {
            currentDate.add(1, 'second');
            const diff = releaseDate.diff(currentDate);
            const diffDuration = moment.duration(diff);
            const difference = +releaseDate - +currentDate;

            return console.log(`
                ${diffDuration.months()} months
                ${diffDuration.days()} days
                ${diffDuration.hours()} hours
                ${diffDuration.minutes()} minutes
                ${diffDuration.seconds()} seconds left!`);
        } 

        console.log('boom! End ticker');

        return clearInterval(this.vars.interval);
    }

};

calc.render();
```

current output

> ```
>             0 months
>             12 days
>             20 hours
>             51 minutes
>             0 seconds left!
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Getting the interval to work

You wrote this:

```
setInterval(this.nextTick(), 1000);
```

...when you probably meant this:

```
setInterval(this.nextTick, 1000);
```

In the first example `this.nextTick()` gets evaluated before the `setInterval`, so the interval tries to work on `nextTick()`'s return value instead of the function itself.  This would be useful if `nextTick()` returned a function, but in this case it returns a `clearInterval()`, which has no return value -- so you wind up running `null` once per second.

In the second example, the function itself is what will be run on the interval.  It's basically a less verbose way of writing:

```
setInterval(function() { this.nextTick() }, 1000)
```

...but that won't quite work here either, because `nextTick()` depends on preserving the same `this`; in a bare function call `this` would revert to the Window object instead of your `calc`.  Preserving `this` can most easily be done with a fat arrow function:

```
setInterval(()=>{this.nextTick()}, 1000);
```

#### Updating the time on each interval

Meanwhile, a second, unrelated issue: you were trying to increment the internal `currentDate` variable on each tick with `currentDate.add(1, 'second')`, but never assigned that new value anywhere -- and also re-filled that variable from the (unmodified) input field each time, meaning you'd always get the same result.  Instead you can write the new value into the input field, where it will be picked up on the next tick:

```
this.elements.currentDate.value = currentDate.add(1, 'second');
```

(Or, alternatively, you could only read from the form field if `currentDate` is empty, and otherwise depend solely on the internal variable.  Or better yet, since what you're looking for is the current time, skip the form field *and* the internal variable, and just use `Date()`.

In general it's safest to depend on one source of truth, rather than using both an internal variable and a DOM element to hold the same piece of data and having to keep them in synch.)

Working example:

```js
const calc = {

    vars: {
        interval: null,
        releaseDate: null,
        currentDate: null
    },

    elements: {
        releaseAt: document.getElementById('release-at'), // 2018-08-31 14:24:00
        currentDate: document.getElementById('current-date') // 2018-08-18 17:32:59
    },

    render () {
        moment().format();
        this.nextTick();
        this.vars.interval = setInterval(()=>{this.nextTick()}, 1000);
    },

    nextTick () {
        let releaseDate = moment(this.elements.releaseAt.value);
        let currentDate = moment(this.elements.currentDate.value);

        if (currentDate.isBefore(releaseDate)) {
            this.elements.currentDate.value = currentDate.add(1, 'second');
            const diff = releaseDate.diff(currentDate);
            const diffDuration = moment.duration(diff);
            const difference = +releaseDate - +currentDate;

            return console.log(`
                ${diffDuration.months()} months
                ${diffDuration.days()} days
                ${diffDuration.hours()} hours
                ${diffDuration.minutes()} minutes
                ${diffDuration.seconds()} seconds left!`);
        } 

        console.log('boom! End ticker');

        return clearInterval(this.vars.interval);
    }

};

calc.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<input id="release-at" value="2018-08-31 14:24:00">
<input id="current-date" value="2018-08-18 17:32:59">
```

Comment: Hi ok the functions runs now every second but it does not subtract another 1 second after the first call, thus whats the difference between calling a function like this foo() and foo

Comment: I just updated the answer to fix the never-changing time; will add more explanation of foo() vs foo as well.

Comment: I probably Need some Sleep, but shouldnt this update the innerHtml every each Elements every second? https://kopy.io/qaFy9